# SSN Validation in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a business requirement where in i need to display SSN Field into three separate text boxes and if any one of the textbox is blank and user clicks save, I need to display a common error message on top of the SSN Field saying- "SSN is required field". I have added required field attribute on the view model on all these fields so i am getting three edit messages saying SSN is required. how to present only one edit in this case ?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2

My view model is like this

```
[Required]
SSN_FirstThreeDigits
[Required]
SSN_SecondTwoDigits
[Required]
SSN_ThirdFourDigits
```

Any suggestions

Thanks
Subu

Comment: FYI, there are 4 last digits, not 3.

Comment: sure. it was my typo. any approach suggestions

Answer (score 2):

SSNValidator.com now has an API for validating social security numbers. Data elements include whether or not the number was issued, approximate date of issuance, state of issuance and if it was used in a death claim. Go to the site and click the API/Batch Processing links for details.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mvc.ValidationTookit Alpha Release: Conditional Validation with MVC 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx) can do this.

Answer (score -1):

You may need a custom model binder. Please have a look at [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx) article and see how he validates date of birth